# LaTeX alignment problems in Anki

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, anki

I want to use Anki to write down mathematical formulas, but whenever I do so and insert any kind of text before, they come out very misaligned to the right. Here is a little example:

```
[latex]
A sum is called telescopic if written in such a form:
\[\sum_{k=p}^q (a_{k+1} - a_k)\]
Simplify this sum.
[/latex]
```

[image: What Anki shows me.]

If I do not write any text, then the formulas are properly aligned in the middle.
The only workaround I have found as of now is enclosing each chunk of text in its own [latex]...[/latex], but that is very tedious, makes the code clunky and results in its own spacing problems (this time vertically, as I cannot space it properly). Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you put the text inside the latex environment and not just the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the tag for LaTeX formula:

```
A sum is called telescopic if written in such a form:
[$]\sum_{k=p}^q (a_{k+1} - a_k)[/$]
Simplify this sum.
```

[image]

And if you change the alignment setting for the card to `text-align: left;`

It looks like this:

[image]